What level of statistical significance to choose for test of equaility of seemingly unrelated regression coefficients?
It is possible to compare effects from models estimated as seemingly unrelated [1] [2] [3]. DVs may be related, IVs may be related, or both may be true. In any event, analysts test for equality of regression coefficients whose significance has already been assessed because they are themselves of substantive interest (as in the usual regression models).

Would you choose a level of statistical significance for the test of equality that is similar to--or in the same way that you choose--the level of statistical significance for the regression coefficients?

Alternatively, would you choose

a higher significance level for the equality test, say 10%? e.g. because the test of difference is expected to be more difficult given the initial interest in the coefficients in the respective models.
a lower significance level for the equality test, say 1%? e.g. because the test is conditional on detecting the coefficients in the respective models in the first place.



Cast in more general terms: Does the choice of statistical test have implications for what level of statistical significance to choose?
To be sure, the question reflects a frequentist view.

I'll start from some general considerations regarding the meaning and choice of the test level, and then later address whether this should depend on the test run.
An $\alpha$ level of significance means that if the null hypothesis were true, and many different data sets are collected, and the test is applied on all these data sets, $\alpha$ would be the expected relative frequency of rejection (the relative frequency in case the number of data set becomes larger and larger). The rationale for choosing $\alpha$ low, like 1% or 5%, is that then if the null hypothesis is rejected, this happens because the data set show something that is really surprising and unexpected under the null hypothesis.
This logic applies to all tests. When choosing $\alpha$,one needs to balance the probability to reject a true null hypothesis (type I error; which should be low, so $\alpha$ should be low) against the type II error probability, i.e., the probability to not reject in case the null hypothesis is in fact false. This depends on how exactly the null hypothesis is false, so it will not be a unique value, however generally the smaller $\alpha$, the larger the type II error probability will be, so these two push in opposite directions, so to say, regarding the choice of $\alpha$.
In practice, one thing to do is to set up realistic or relevant models (parameter values) for the alternative hypothesis. Then the type II error probability can be computed (note that you also may not want the type II error probability too low in case that the null hypothesis is violated but the true parameter value is very close to it, because in terms of interpretation, this may mean that in fact "nothing big is going on" and you may not want to claim significance too easily in such a case). The next important thing is to think about the consequences of committing a type I and type II error, i.e., how bad would these be in the actual application case? A larger $\alpha$ can be chosen if indeed rejecting the null hypothesis doesn't have very bad consequences (for example if this only means in the given situation that a somewhat more complex course of action is taken next which may be a bit tedious but doesn't involve big risks; in such a situation the null hypothesis may just mean that the situation is rather simple and can be handled in a simple way). One could try to formalise such considerations involving a quantitative loss that goes with each type of error (although some then would say you then should also consider prior probabilities of the different possibilities and analyse the situation in a Bayesian manner). One may also take into account how many tests are run in a study, and apply certain corrections for multiple testing (usually implying that individual tests are run at smaller $\alpha$ in order to keep the combined type I error probability over many tests small).
In many situations these considerations are complicated and very hard to quantify ("should I publish a paper that makes a claim that may be of some interest but immediate practical consequences are either not clear or extremely hard to predict?"). For this reason many just choose a "standard level" of 0.05 or 0.01.
It may well be you know all this, but the implication for your question is that the choice of $\alpha$ depends on knowledge of the situation and practical consequences of type I and type II errors. Just considering the formal problem and test without any specification of consequences or potential loss doesn't have implications on the choice of $\alpha$. In short, I don't agree that $\alpha$ should depend on the chosen test.
Also keep in mind that unless in practice a binary decision regarding a concrete action needs to be made, interpreting a test in a binary manner like "reject/not reject" reduces information strongly and has the somewhat silly consequence that for example, if $\alpha=0.05$, a p-value of 0.045 is interpreted in a drastically different way from $p=0.052$, even though in fact the "message" from these p-values is very similar. Tests have been criticised a lot for encouraging binary black/white interpretations when in fact the data may show many shades of grey. So one way of handling this is to look at the p-value and to use more nuanced wording (and also to think in a more nuanced manner than rather taking the null hypothesis as either proven false or "accepting" it) like "there is some weak but not very strong evidence against the null hypothesis" for $p$ around 0.05, "there is very strong evidence" for $p<0.001$ and so on, rather than getting obsessed with a fixed significance level.

Thank you Christian. I like that you took care to explain tests of significance. Specifically, you remind me that the type II downside of still lower $\alpha$ is that effects may not be detected if they just happen to be small in the specific data at hand. I also wondered whether you may more explicitly address my question: e.g. testing for a difference between coefficients from different models 'feels next-level' above and beyond testing the individual coefficients in respective models in the first place; as if it is expected harder to detect - - would that suggest a higher $\alpha$?

@Johan As I wrote, I can't say anything without knowing the situation and potential consequences of the involved decisions. I don't agree with the idea that $\alpha$ should formally depend on the chosen test. What you can do is think of differences that you may want to detect with high probability, and then simulate artificial data with such differences, run the test, and evaluate the type II error probability depending on $\alpha$. That will show you whether the kind of differences relevant to you can be detected with good probability (it may even be possible to figure it out theoretically).

First, your statement "I don't agree that $\alpha$ should depend on the chosen test" is very clear, and I suggest an edit adding it to your answer. Second, when you write "knowing the situation and potential consequences of the involved decision", are you referring to 1) the specific data being modelled and tested 2) the consequences of type I and II errors and 3) the decision about what $\alpha$ to pick? ps. thanks for suggesting using simulations to derive the required $\alpha$ (I suppose you refer to those simulations called Monte Carlo).

By "decision" I mean that the sharp distinction between reject and not reject as enforced by the significance level only makes sense if this has consequences for action, and therefore computing whether a test is significant or not implies a decision what action to take. (This kind of decision is usually treated by decision theory.)

Ok. What about "situation" and "consequences" - what did you mean by that? Is the "situation" referring to specific data and models? Is "consequences" referring to consequences of type II and II errors upon rejecting/not rejecting H0?

I refer to the real situation in which the test is applied, meaning of the data, aim of research, real decisions made based on the analysis. Otherwise, comments are not for extended discussion, and I have said what I had to say.  Also my response is intentionally more general than your question, so please don't edit it to make it more narrow.
